# What is the difference between globalposition and localposition in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

Somehow I'm getting same values for both, I'm not able to understand the difference between global and local position in flutter.

```
RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
Offset position = getBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
var local = getBox.globalToLocal(update.globalPosition);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GlobalPosition is the coordinate of a point on-screen with the top-left corner of the screen as the origin. Whereas LocalPosition is the coordinates of a point inside a RenderBox with the top-left corner of the RenderBox as the origin. If you are getting the same value, it means that your RenderBox top-left corner is the same as the screen top-left corner.

Comment: More precisely, it just means that your RenderBox top-left corner is the same as the screen top-left corner.

Comment: @MarcG yeah that sounds more accurate.

Comment: remove that line "If you are getting the same value, then it just means that your RenderBox is covering the whole screen", it's wrong