# What is delta, globalPosition, localPosition and primaryDelta in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am struggling to understand the properties `delta`, `globalPosition`, `localPosition` and `primaryDelta` of `DragUpdateDetails`. I read the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html) for `DragUpdateDetails` but it didn't really help much.

I found some question asked: [What is primaryDelta and delta in DragUpdateDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822356/what-is-primarydelta-and-delta-in-dragupdatedetails) and [What is the difference between globalposition and localposition in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783363/what-is-the-difference-between-globalposition-and-localposition-in-flutter). First one has no answer whereas second one only has explanation for `globalPosition` and `localPosition`.

This is a sample code for dragging a container:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double _xPosition = 0;
  double _yPosition = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  top: _yPosition,
                  left: _xPosition,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails e) {
                      setState(() {
                        _xPosition += e.delta.dx;
                        _yPosition += e.delta.dy;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example why are we using `delta` but not `globalPosition` or `localPosition`. I mean of course dragging will not work as expected but how to know when to use `delta` or `globalPosition` or `localPosition`?

Can someone provide me a quick explanation for these properties? It would really mean a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Source code of [`DragUpdateDetails`class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html):

> delta → Offset
> The amount the pointer has moved in the coordinate space of the event receiver since the previous update

Meaning, The distance covered by dragging since the last pointer contact. Delta gives `dx` for horizontal distance and `dy` for vertical distance.

> primaryDelta → double
> The amount the pointer has moved along the primary axis in the coordinate space of the event receiver since the previous update

`primaryDelta` gives the absolute distance in only one primary direction of dragging, meaning if the drag is primarily in horizontal axis(GestureDragUpdateCallback + Horizontal only) then this value represents the drag distance in the horizontal axis. If the drag in is vertical axis (GestureDragUpdateCallback + Vertical only) then this value represents the drag amount in the vertical axis.

**Note**: if the `GestureDragUpdateCallback` is for a two-dimensional drag (e.g., a pan), then this value is `null`.

> globalPosition → Offset
> The pointer's global position when it triggered this update.

The position of the pointer on the screen with reference to the whole screen area and origin point at the `top-left` corner of the screen. Global Position gives `x` for horizontal co-ordinate and `y` for vertical co-ordinate

> localPosition → Offset
> The local position in the coordinate system of the event receiver at which the pointer contacted the screen.

The position of the pointer just like the `global position`, except the referential frame being the widget/render object instead of the whole screen. Here, The widget is the one that has received the pointer contact.

## Explanation with respect to the example code

According to the example code that is provided, I can safely say that when you are dealing with the positioning of any draggable widget you must have an initial position.

For the initial position, `globalPosition` or `localPosition` can be used. Which one to use is specific to the widget tree and use of the app.

Once the initial position is set, you can use `delta` or `primaryDelta` to find the new position for the draggable widget to move to when dragged by following formula:

`newXPosition` = `initialXPosition` + (`dx` or `primaryDelta` in horizontal axis)

`newYPosition` = `initialYPosition` + (`dy` or `primaryDelta` in vertical axis)

One thing to keep in mind while using `delta` and `primaryDelta` is that, if the widget can/should recognize the drag events in both axis, only `delta` will be provided, `primaryDelat` will be `null`.

Otherwise, if only one direction drag is expected then using only `primaryDelta` will work as expected, at this point `delta` will have only one value as a `non-zero` value and other as `0` based on which direction the drag is to be recognized.

Let me know if you have any other questions about this in the comments.

Comment: As you said "globalPosition = The position of the pointer on the screen with reference to the whole screen area and origin point at the top-left corner of the screen.". So, shouldn't the dragging position calculation be something like `_xPosition = e.globalPosition.dx - width_of_container; _yPosition = e.globalPosition.dy - height_of_container;` because we are moving the container based on the position of pointer on the screen?

Comment: Okay I got this now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @DRAGON I think you understand this now, but just for the sake of completion, 
For the question in the comment: you already get the `delta` value from the drag update details, so there's no need to calculate it again to use for moving the container, however, there's no rule to use only `delta`, anything is allowed which works for you. Keep in mind that if you do it yourself,  it may cause unintended performance problems if not done carefully.